# Copy Column if first row contains certain value, then paste to another sheet Macros VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm trying to search for a specific column in my spreadsheet, if the first row has a value then I would copy that whole column and paste it to another sheet. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:W1")
        If Cell.Value = "IX_OCN" Then
            ' TODO
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm not to sure what to put in the if loop to copy the whole column and then paste. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet2").Column(Cell.Column).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("SheetPaste").Column(1)` ?

Comment: got an error saying object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Oh, whoops sorry: `Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(Cell.Column).EntireColumn.Copy Sheets("SheetPaste").Columns(1)`

Comment: brilliant thanks mate